# Wireless router MAC address using Python

Tags: python, mac-address, arp, ipconfig

1) How will I get my wireless routers MAC address (which I connected to) from my system.**ipconfig /all** give my local machine network card MAC address.

2) And "**arp -a**" give MAC address what I wanted but is there any other way to find wireless router MAC address using Python?

3) How often arp table updates? If network change or MAC address change will update happens in ARP table affect immediately?

Comment: have you ever tried netifaces? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @manoelhc I tried using netifaces but I don't know how to get the mac address of the router which my system is connected to. What I know is to get IP address and mac address of my network card. Would you mind telling me how to get my router details using netifaces if you know (some link)? If I get it Do I have to provide my router ID and Password to access? Is there way without providing it?

Comment: @halfer Thanks for letting me know that. I didn't know about that as I am new to StackOverflow, But I will take care of this in future questions.